# Polymorphism Fail

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, polymorphism

I've got a very simple polymorphism set-up: base class with virtual method, derived class that overloads the method.  The slight twist is that they are template classes and the base class's method does things that would cause compilation to fail for the derived class.  I thought that this would not be a problem since the base class's method is overloaded, but apparently it is a problem.

I have stripped down the code as much as I could to illustrate the problem.  Here it is.

DspBuffer.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

template <class T>
class DspBuffer {
 public:
    std::vector<T> buf;

    DspBuffer<T>(unsigned size) {buf = std::vector<T>(size);}
    virtual void sort() {std::sort(buf.begin(), buf.end());}
};
```

ComplexDspBuffer.h

```
#include <complex>
#include "DspBuffer.h"

template <class T>
class ComplexDspBuffer : public DspBuffer<T> {
 public:
    ComplexDspBuffer<T>(unsigned size) : DspBuffer<T>(size) {}
    void sort() {assert(false);}
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ComplexDspBuffer.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ComplexDspBuffer< std::complex<double> > buf(1);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to me that this shouldn't be a problem to build, but the compiler (Xcode 5.0.2) produces errors like the following- "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/algorithm:644:97: Invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::__1::complex' and 'const std::__1::complex')".

It is referring to a templated __less function that is used by std::sort.  It is, in other words, building the DspBuffer< std::complex >.sort() method even though it can't be called, or at least isn't called.  Am I doing something wrong, or is having a base class method that cannot work with the derived class's data type a non-starter?

Comment: Where is `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Good catch.  I edited both my code and the question, but the errors are the same.

Comment: Would void sort() = delete; be a better option for inheritance? I now understand base class is called. Hmmm..

Comment: Maybe a std::conditional is needed when instantiating base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no `operator <` defined for `std::complex<T>`, and `std::sort` requires this operation to be defined.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  My question is more along the lines of why is the base class' sort method being compiled at all?

Comment: Why would you think that an instantiation of the template means that the function won't be compiled?  Are you getting confused with `link time` elimination of the functions that are not called?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right that the pruning would happen at link time.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should get your terminology right: there is a difference between *overloading* which means to have one function name being used with different arguments and *overriding* which means replacing a virtual function with a more specialized version in a derived class. As far as I can tell, in all cases where you used overloading you actually meant overriding.

Any concrete virtual function can always be called, even if it is overridden: you can just qualify the function call with the name of the corresponding base class, e.g.:

```
buf.DspBuffer<std::complex<double>>::sort();
```

would call the base class version. Further, during the lifetime of the object, it actually changes its type: in the constructor and destructor of a class, the type of the object is of the constructor's or destructor's class, even if it eventually becomes a more derived class. For this purposes, all concrete virtual functions are instantiated.

The easiest way out is to specialize the implementation of `DspBuffer<std::complex<double>>::sort()`, e.g.:

```
template <>
void DspBuffer<std::complex<double>>::sort() {
    std::sort(buf.begin(), buf.end(),
              [](std::complex<double> const& c0, std::complex<double> const& c1) {
                  return c0.real() < c1.real()
                      || (!(c1.real() < c0.real()) && c0.imag() < c1.imag());
              });
}
```

I'm not a big fan of having functions which only assert if they are called, especially if it is possible to provide a perfectly viable implementation: just because the less than operator doesn't make sense for mathematical axioms doesn't mean complex numbers can't be sorted into an order.

Comment: Thanks for the terminology correction and the tip on how to call base class methods- was not aware of that.  I get your point about the sorting criteria being somewhat arbitrary, but I think the cleaner solution will be to have the base class only define those methods that apply to both real and complex numbers, and add the more specialized methods in the derived classes.  Thanks again.